# gets into char *str without malloc, no segfault?

Tags: c, string, malloc, stdin

I've just compiled this C program using Cygwin's gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main (){
    char *str;
    gets(str);
    printf("%s",str);
}
```

Setting aside `gets` is <s>deprecated</s> gone, this is supposed to break since I'm not allocating any memory for str, but it works even with very long inputs. If, for example, I set char str[16] it breaks after exceeding the allocated length by just a few characters.

How come I'm not getting a segmentation fault?

Comment: Probably a pure luck.

Comment: I thought so at first, but every time?

Comment: Your code has a bug. Code with bugs in it doesn't do what you expect. That's why you're supposed to avoid them and fix them when you find them.

Comment: alright, so there is no misterious obscure dynamic allocation taking place here. I'm just using unallocated free memory that may be overrided any time during execution, right?

Comment: I would go with luck, too... Check the value of str. It is supposedly "undefined", but it is likely to be deterministic, meaning it could "by accident" end up pointing to a read/write page of memory for your process. It should still fail for strings large enough (i.e. try strings bigger than your memory page size).

Comment: You're (a) invoking undefined behavior, while simultaneously (b) confusing *defined behavior* with *observed behavior*.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Afaik dereferencing a null pointer will always give you a segfault.

Comment: @WhozCraig To clarify, my real question is: Is there any *defined* behaviour I'm not aware of taking place here and leading to this *observed* results? The answer is no, as I expected. I'm ok with that :-)

Comment: That would be no. The moment you entered into UB, everything else is off the reservation for the rest of your program's unnatural life. (and btw, `gets()` isn't just deprecated, it is outright *gone*). Truth be told the UB isn't even in the guts of `gets()`. By the standard, even *evaluating* an indeterminate variable is UB, which is done while conceiving the value being *passed* to `gets()`. IOW you're in UB before you even call it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: He says the code seems to work, which would mean that printf *is* dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: Undefined behaviour does not mean undeterministic. UB means something will happen, maybe always the same thing on the same platform with the same program, but nobody have defined what. And this is the reason why it will probably happen differently on another platforms or with another although very similar program. Just try to add another variable before or after your `str` ...

Comment: C has next to none runtime system, so it doesn't declare itself responsible to punish you for silly mistakes. If you want to write programs that crash, you are allowed to do so.

It's the responsibility of the operating system to prevent you from crashing itself or other processes (this is not a C functionality). It also allows you to crash your own program if you want to do so.

The baseline is: if you are fiddling with an uninitialized pointer that by chance happens to point into you own processes' address space, the OS allows you to do so, but if it happens to point elsewhere, it stops you.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How can the string be stored by gets and written back to stdout by printf without dereferencing str?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Access memory region pointed to by uninitialized pointer is **undefined behavior**, it could crash, it also could look like working normally. In a word, you cannot predict its behavior.

> How come I'm not getting a segmentation fault?

Uninitialized pointer has an undetermined value, it could point to anywhere, if it points to some big enough writable region accidently, that program will "work" normally.

Comment: I think he's asking for a more technical explanation. Yes, it's undefined behavior, but *why* does it seem to work normally in this case?

Comment: @heinrichj that is why its undefined :)

Comment: @heinrichj Uninitialized pointer has a indetermined value, it could point to anywhere, if it points to some big enough writable region accidently, that program will "work" normally.

Comment: In addition, since you cannot predict what will happen when you invoke UB, dwelling on why a program behaves in a certain manner when you do, is a complete waste of time. It's as if you stand on the street, tossing stones through the windows of your house, then go aside and ponder why some things broke and some did not.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `str` has an undefined value. It means that it simply gets a place on the stack and the value which was there happens to be inside this variable. A possible explication of your behaviour is that a builtin function initializing process environment and invoking your `main` used this place for a meaningful pointer to some accessible memory. The value of this pointer stayed on the stack and when your main was invoked it happened that `str` got this value. But this is just one of possible explications.